# Java Class Loading Flow

Tags: java, runtime, classloader

can anyone give me an idea of how the class loading flow works?,
 What i'm trying  to say is that i need to understand what happend when a developer create a new object eg:

```
User user = new User();
```

where java goes to load the class, I try excluding a class from my build and setting the current thread class loader with a jar that contains the excluded class and run it with no good results.

Comment: I think you can start from JVM specs - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html

Comment: Did you examine the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2) and [JVM Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html)?  You should always do some research before asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found it. Thanks!.
Java looks for the classLoader of the class that contains it.